# numpy.loadtxt() invalid literal for float() error

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror

I'm trying to read a .txt file that is in another directory. The path to get it in Linux command is: `cd 2020_0/01`.

The command I do is:

```
np.loadtxt('2020_0/01/file.txt')
```

and it returns

> invalid literal for float(): 2020_0

Does anyone know why?

I have been able to use this line in an other code. It only fails when I'm using it on another server. So I know the document is readable.

Comment: Does your .txt file have `2020_0` in it? check using `grep '2020_0' 2020_0/01/file.txt` in the terminal.  `numpy.loadtxt(...)` converts all values in the file to floats, and "2020_0" is obviously not a valid one.

Comment: Ohhh yes... I guess that is the probleme. I'll try to jump over those lines.Thank you!!!